# Threadlock for Bottom bracket on Titanium Frame?

Tags: bottom-bracket, lubricant, titanium, threaded-bottom-bracket

I'm looking into installing a bottom bracket for my titanium bike frame. The bottom
bracket that I purchased (SHIMANO ULTEGRA Threaded Bottom Bracket 68/70 mm shell width) seems to have some kind of gel/liquid thread locker on it already. Is it compatible with a titanium frame? Or should I be using anti seize instead?

Answer (score 5):

Use anti-seize on all threaded titanium BB shells. You're fine leaving the pre-applied threadlocker in place, or you could pick it off.

Comment: Related question: the manual for the Ultegra BB says to apply grease to the cups. But won't that defeat the purpose of the threadlock?

Comment: @someguyinafloppyhat Probably. Shimano is oblique about things like this. It's likely that the real purpose of the pre-applied threadlocker is to make things likelier to go okay if someone does everything wrong - no grease and/or inadequate torque.

Answer (score 5):

The grey/white stuff on Shimano BBs is a mild threadlocker I believe. I normally put antiseize on top of it. The substance will still contribute a threadlocking effect by filling gaps, and you have the antiseize there for chemical protection.